# Run Amazon CloudWatch Event every Sunday at 10:00 am UTC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have already read [Amazon CloudWatch Events - Schedule Expressions for Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

Now I want to trigger an event every Sunday at 10:00 am and I am confused if this is correct?

Currently I have `cron(0 10 * * SUN *)` & `cron(0 10 ? * SUN *)`

I don't know the difference between `?` & `*` in Cronjob. So which one is correct is confusing?

**Side Note**

What is the difference between `rate` and `schedule` because `rate` is simpler to use so I can do like `rate(7 days)` but I don't know when it will run?

Will it run every 7 days from the moment of deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That page says:

> You can't specify the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields in the same cron expression. If you specify a value (or a `*`) in one of the fields, you must use a `?` (question mark) in the other.

It also says:

> A rate expression starts when you create the scheduled event rule, and then runs on its defined schedule.

Comment: I deployed a simple hello world & it worked. Thanks man for helping. Appreciate it. The answer `cron(0 10 ? * SUN *)` is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

To run every Sunday at 10:00 AM UTC,

`cron(0 10 ? * SUN *)` or `cron(0 10 ? * 1 *)`

**Use ? for Day-of-month part when Day-of-week has a value(here, SUN or 1)** because when you want to run only on a specific day of the week, you can't use *, you *can't say run everyday*. Instead, we *should say run one or another day of the month*, using ?, which will be every Sunday of the month because we have set Day-of-week.

Refer [Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) for all details